# VB.net Reset SMTP Connection

Tags: vb.net, email

I coded an application that I use to send certain mails with. It contains a list of email addresses that can be selected as the receiver. Everytime I send a mail to one receiver, lets say 1@gmail.com, everythink works out just fine. If I send a second email to a new receiver, lets say 2@gmail.com, my email is sent to 1@gmail.com aswell as 2@gmail.com. I tried using the Dispose() Function, but that gave me a bunch of errors. 
It must somehow be possible to fix that error I guess. I tried about restarting the SMTP session.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a new email address, you can clear the previous ones

```
 email.To.Clear()
 email.To.Add ("2@gmail.com")
```